Kubuntu 24.04 Missing Microsoft Accounts from "Online Accounts"
I just finished a minimal Kubuntu 24.02 installation. In my "Online Accounts", I cannot add any Microsoft 365 accounts because the option(s) are missing. Anyone know what to install/configure  to get them?


The "Online Accounts" integration doesn't really do anything with MS365.  There is no OneCloud integrated client, nor do most applications utilize the Online Accounts integrations for many of these other integrations. As such, I don't think MS365 was considered in the Online Accounts tooling.  Even if it were included, it wouldn't really unlock much.  There's a difference between MS365 in Online Accounts and integration with Active Directory which is the main 24.04 perk if you need to deploy LInux in a Windows-homed AD environment/network.

All the documentation for the file browsing tools indicate that once you create your account at a system level, you can sync and navigate to OneDrive folders without configuring anything else. To do that, I have to be able to select M365 when creating an online account. I cannot do that because it isn't an option, although it appears to be in the screenshots for the tools I'm trying to set up. Nautilus is one such tool. You can see the instructions here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/set-up-onedrive-file-access-in-ubuntu
